# my sql query failing and yet returns no mySQL errors

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have been writing php and mySQL functions all day and as I was writing the simplest part of my project I have hit a wall.

The function should simply count how many entries are in the database and return that number (If there is a more simple way please let me know, this is my first php + mysql project)

Here is the code:

```
function quoteCount(){
    global $db;
    $totalQuoteNum = array();
    $query = "SELECT * FROM Quotes";
    $result_set = mysqli_query($db, $query)
    or die ("Query $query failed ".mysqli_error($db)); //fails here
    $totalQuoteNum = mysql_num_rows($result_set) 
    or die ('couldnt count rows'.mysqli_error($db));
    echo 'COUNTED EVERYTHING!!!';
    return $totalQuoteNum;
};
```

Now when the die statement prints I get the string but not the mysqli error.

Things I have tried and ruled out:

1. $db is correct
2. query works in mysql
3. I wasnt sure if the database was connected, so I added the connect inside this function and stil nothing.

Any ideas? From what I see it should work and its not giving me any error to work from. Please help!

Comment: Post the output from `var_dump($db);`

Comment: If you just want to count the number of rows using `SELECT count(*) FROM Quotes` will be a lot more efficient.

Comment: @jason output is: string(7) "quoteit"
 , quoteit being the name of my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it seems as though `$db` is the database name.

Functions such as [`mysqli_query()`](http://php.net/mysqli_query) expect a database link (resource), not simply the database name.

This resource is created by [constructing a new mysqli object](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.connect.php). Following your procedural style, use `mysqli_connect()`.

Comment: Aha! You were right, I want back to my connect function and made it global now I am getting a link in $db, however i am getting a database not selected error. I'm sure I can figure it out form here.

Comment: Yes, you'll need to update which *global* variable you are using in this function. Sounds like you connected but have not called `mysqli_select_db()`.

Comment: Now I am having trouble with my select :(

Comment: I figured it out, I didn't use select I just specified it in the query "SELECT * FROM quoteit.Quotes"